# How to print the inner contents of a div with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The html of the website looks like:

```
<div class="breed-image">
    <img src = "link to image">
</div>
```

When I do this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
for link in soup.find_all(class_='breed-image'):

    print(link)
```

All it does is print out:

```
<div class="breed-image">
</div>
```

I have also tried print(link.text)

All that does is print out:

```
None
```

Any kind of help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options:

```
>>> soup.img['src']
'link to image'
>>> for link in soup.find_all('img'):
...     print(link['src'])
...
link to image
```

Comment: For the first option it gives me the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` and for the second it just does not print out anything

Comment: @Jonation McMurray here is the link if you want to see the all of the html https://dog.ceo/dog-api/breeds-image-random.php

Comment: It looks like this page has no img in the HTML, it gets added by some embedded Javascript - so if you're downloading this page e.g. with `responses` module, the image will not be added as the JS isn't executed. This question may help with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python

Comment: @MarkW yes, that's AFTER the JavaScript has executed - the JS inserts the `img` tag, without executing the JS source, there is no img tag. You can see this if you use 'View Source' in your browser instead of 'Inspect'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be better off hitting the API that this page calls to get its image:

```
In [13]: r = requests.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')

In [14]: r.json()
Out[14]:
{'message': 'https://dog.ceo/api/img/terrier-dandie/n02096437_1790.jpg',
 'status': 'success'}
```